# static variable loop not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, functions, filters, post-formats, oembed

I have a function in my wordpress theme that deletes the first embedded video in a video post. See code below. This is in the functions.php file.

```
/* - function that hides first video in post content - */

function process_embed( $embed ){

    if ( is_single() && get_post_format() === 'video' ) {
        static $post_video_num = 0;

        $post_video_num++;

        // Hide first video in the post content on single video post page
        if ( 1 === $post_video_num ) {
            return '';
        }
    }

    return $embed;
}


add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'process_embed', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'video_embed_html', 'process_embed' ); // Jetpack
```

As you can see, if the post is a single post and it's a video format, it will declare a static variable and iterate it everytime a video is in the post. If the static variable `$post_video_num` is 1 (meaning the first video in the post) it is replaced with blank, removing the first embed video.

**This code works fine in my development environment on my local machine. However, it doesn't seem to work on my live server**. That is the problem.

While I was debugging, after echoing out the `$post_video_num` variable, I found out that it won't remove the first video because the variable `$post_video_num` is 8 (instead of 1, as it should be).

After echoing out the `$post_video_num` numbers, what is happening is that it echoes out the numbers 1-8 on top of the page, then echoes out 8-12 in place of where the first video should be. Specifically on the live server, the function seems to loop multiple times, which is why it doesn't work.

The core problem, which is what is puzzling me, is that this function works as intended on my local machine but not on the live server, as it does this strange looping thing which I can't explain.

What would cause this function to work on my local machine and not the live server? Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks! I hope this makes sense. You're help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two filters which trigger the function, that's why, I guess, it's running multiple times.
Maybe try disabling one of the two filters to determine which one is the one you need.

Comment: I have just tried that. It hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Some guy had a problem with jetpack and "embed_oembed_html" filter, check out the latest note here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_oembed_html/ maybe it will help )))

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function realistic_get_first_embed_video($post_id)
 {
     $post = get_post($post_id);
     $content = do_shortcode(apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content));
     $embeds = get_media_embedded_in_content($content);
     if (!empty($embeds)) {
         //check what is the first embed containg video tag, youtube or vimeo
         $counter = 0;
         foreach ($embeds as $embed) {
            // Check condition if count is 0 then 
            // it is the first iteration
            if( $counter == 0 ) {
                return '';
            }

             /*
             if (strpos($embed, 'video') || strpos($embed, 'youtube') || strpos($embed, 'vimeo') || strpos($embed, 'dailymotion') || strpos($embed, 'vine') || strpos($embed, 'wordPress.tv') || strpos($embed, 'hulu')) {
                 return $embed;
             }
             */
            $counter = $counter + 1;
         }
     } else {
         //No video embedded found
         return;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what that does differently? What's the commented-out block in the middle for? This doesn't look like it actually returns anything as-is. What's the counter for?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).